# Operation with variable argument list in UML

Tags: c++, uml

I'm trying to model a class that has a method with a variable argument list (like `printf()`) in UML. Any idea what to write in the parameter string?

Comment: Does your UML tool support reverse engineering of the code? Did you try what you'll get there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I can see from the UML 2.3 superstructure spec, it is possible to define the multiplicity attribute for operation parameters. Thus a set of optional parameters could be expressed with a defined parameter and applying a multiplicity of [0..*].

Comment: I still need to provide a type which is not the case with printf(). If I use void as type, Enterprise Architect generates `void printf(void[0..*] args);` which is not what I want. I'm not sure if this is due to "incorrect" UML or due to a flaw in Enterprise Architect though.

Comment: Did you set the parameter multiplicity via EA's parameter dialog?
Did you try reverse engineering C++ code with a variable argument list?
It could be possible, that EA's code generation is somehow flawed about this, but that should be easy to fix in the standard C++ code generation template.

Comment: It works for me when I set the arguments name to `...` and its multiplicity via EA's parameter dialog. It feels like an ugly hack but it gets the job done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ ellipsis can't be modeled under UML through a multiplicity because ellipsis is not one parameter whose type is a collection of values of a given type, C++ ellipsis is very specific. To use a parameter named "..." is the right way if don't have an other possibility  (under Bouml the ellipsis can be added without using a pseudo parameter named "...").

**g-makulik** is also right, when you don't know how to model something the reverse can help a lot.

Comment: In Bouml, what would be the representation of the C++ ellipsis when doing an UML export?